# Audio playlist autoplaying queue on iOS

Tags: ios, audio, next.js, react-player

Greetings to all fellow front-end coders.

I have quite a headache because of Apple's autoplay policy. As you've probably experienced, you can't autoplay a video / audio element with sound without user interaction. (I'm referring to [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari#3030251))

I'm currently trying to create my own music web application that will support playlists. I work with the Next.js framework and use react-player as player. Since it does not natively support playlists, I created a two-player pendulum system, where one plays the current sound file and the other loads the next. Then their roles change.

Everything works great in all browsers, except those on iOS, because this player uses autoplay to start playing.

I've been worried about this for several days. I've already thought about letting an Apple product users press play button every time a song changes as a punishment, but of course it's not a good solution.

I think a lot of you have encountered this and you have certainly found a solution. Please help me :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.